# Titan Graph DB: handling Transaction in IdGraph

Tags: graph-databases, titan

I was going through this [Titan article](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Multi-Threaded-Transactions). Here they are talking about transaction in Titan graph

```
Vertex v1 = g.addVertex(null);
//Do many other things
TransactionalGraph tx = g.newTransaction();
Vertex v2 = tx.addVertex(null);
v2.setProperty("uniqueName","foo");
tx.commit();
g.addEdge(null,v1,g.getVertex(v2),"related"); //Need to load v2 into outer transaction
//Do many other things
g.commit(); // Likely to fail due to lock congestion
```

This is ok if I am using `TitanGraph` but how should I handle transaction when using `IdGraph`? Shall i do something like below:

```
    // baseGraph is TitanGraph,   g is IdGraph

    TransactionalGraph tx = baseGraph.newTransaction();
    Vertex v = g.addVertex(pageId);

    v.setProperty("prop1",       prop1);
    v.setProperty("prop2",       prop2);
    v.setProperty("prop3",       prop3);

    tx.commit();

    .....create some edges here

    g.commit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question.  If I were doing that, my instinct would be to use `baseGraph` to start the new transaction, then wrap the created `tx` in `IdGraph` as follows:

```
// baseGraph is TitanGraph,   g is IdGraph
TransactionalGraph tx = baseGraph.newTransaction();
IdGraph txId = new IdGraph(tx);
Vertex v = txId.addVertex(pageId);

v.setProperty("prop1",       prop1);
v.setProperty("prop2",       prop2);
v.setProperty("prop3",       prop3);

txId.commit();

.....create some edges here using txId

txId.commit();
```

Wrapping the `baseGraph` in `IdGraph` only decorates `g` with that feature.  Since `tx` is a  "new" graph instance, it too needs to be wrapped as well to get decorated with `IdGraph` features.  Note that the above code will not work until this issue is resolved:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/592

I didn't realize that such a wrapping was not possible until this question came up.

Comment: Hey @stephen I was waiting for you man. I knew only you will give answer. Very few users are interested in such beautiful DB Titan on SO. Well I am also doing same thing `baseGraph` to start the new transaction and inside that transaction i am doing all `IDgraph` operation. right?

Comment: i made my answer more specific.

Comment: where is `tx.commit()` ??? i think the first `txId.commit();` should be `tx.commit()`

Comment: When I was tring `new IdGraph(tx)` I had to do `IdGraph idGraph = new IdGraph((KeyIndexableGraph) txGraph);` cos there is nothing like previous thing and when I did this it shows `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported threaded transaction graph. Call on parent graph`..What is the problem with code that i have suggested in my question??

Comment: Hmmm...you may not be able to use `IdGraph` in the context of a `ThreadedTransactionalGraph`.  Apparently `IdGraph` needs to know the "features" of a `Graph` instance and the `ThreadedTransactionalGraph` doesn't support that.  Not sure why.  The problem with your original code is that you are mutating the graph in the context of `g` and not the `ThreadedTransactionalGraph`, thus your changes aren't tied to the transaction your created.  Note that unless you are trying to write to a transaction over multiple threads use of `newTrnasaction` is unecessary.

Comment: I'll ask the Titan Core Team about why "Features" are not implemented on `ThreadedTransactionalGraph`.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: After talking to the Titan Core Team, it seems that there is no solution at this time.  I've created an issue: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/592  Please track the resolution there.  Be certain that your use case requires multi-threaded transactions. Judging from other posts you've made, I'm not so sure you need to use them.  Updated my answer a bit.

Comment: Yah after facing this issue I jumped back to `TitanGraph` for the sack of Transaction. I liked `IdGraph` graph for custom id assignment easily. But i solved that issue also by using `g.makeKey("myid").dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).unique().make()` So for me i solved my problem